# How can I set Regular Expression on TextBox?

Tags: wpf, regex, textbox

How can I set a regular expression on [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) TextBox?
I want the textbox to accept input in some predefined format.
Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, please have a look at this question's answer. It seems to be exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103765/wpf-textbox-how-to-define-some-restriction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options:

- You can create a `ValidationRule` subclass (see below) and add it to your Binding's Validators property
- You can set a `ValidationCallback` on your bound property, throw an exception if the value is wrong, and use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681406/wpf-databinding-watch-for-thrown-exceptions/1682888#1682888) for easily showing validation errors
- You can create an attached property that registers an event handler for the  TextBox.TextChanged property and implement your own validation error notification mechanism
- You can use a normal TextBox with an TextBox_Changed handler in code behind
- You can handle PreviewKeyDown and PreviewTextInput from an attached property as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103765/wpf-textbox-how-to-define-some-restriction)
- You can use a [masked text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481059/where-can-i-find-a-free-masked-textbox-in-wpf) as mentioned by Jan

For arbitrary regexes I would generally use WPF's built-in validation features or do the validation on the bound property.  For specific needs the PreviewKeyDown/PreviewTextInput or masked text box might be better.

Here is how you would create a ValidationRule subclass:

```
public class RegexValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
  ... // Declare Regex property and Message property

  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
  {
    if(Regex.IsMatch((string)value))
      return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    else
      return new ValidationResult(false, Message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can check at the changed event or you could use what's called a masked textbox.

Comment: i am not able to see masked textbox in wpf

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481059/where-can-i-find-a-free-masked-textbox-in-wpf