# Validating a XAML TextBox/RichTextBox to accept an email address?

Tags: c#, string, validation, xaml, textbox

I have a TextBox/RichTextBox in XAML that I want to validate to make sure it contains a string with an '@' symbol. I am using this feature to accept an appropriate email address. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a ValidationRule as detailed in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734511/how-can-i-set-regular-expression-on-textbox). As for the actual RegEx to use, it depends on how detailed you want the check to be.

(Very) Simple: ^[\w.]+@[\w-]+.[a-z]+$

Complex options: [Many options available](http://regexlib.com/%28X%281%29A%28SPZe5Gc5PVw7bXeo-JC-JvWlPC4kcrFeFQkLE5lAqxypxxLW7SO8fR8vVVhMgnXRJ34l0ptP94NQA45uil80fne_qVjhv6BpqYr6uc6aRbMUo81vH4PykowfvhhWEGp3d6C2Pm-bgY4uUxl6peGxovDuX6H0UTVxWUJS0XodA6qXEjOI4eY1OuHMuD36-Gt20%29%29/DisplayPatterns.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can Get the textbox text string from C# and see if it contains the stuff you need for email
example

### XAML & C#

```
<TextBox Name="txt1" Text="abc@def.com"/>

C#*****************************

bool valid = txt1.Text.contains("@")

if(valid)
{
    whololo
}
```