# How can I check textbox is begining only alphabets?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to start with alphabet in textbox. How can I check textbox is begining only alphabets ? For example:

- N4534 -- True
- NN435 -- True
- 2N645 -- False
- ?N645 -- False

Thanks

Comment: I would use regular expression: `^[a-zA-z].*$`

Comment: I think you could use regular expression [Regular expression on TextBox in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734511/how-can-i-set-regular-expression-on-textbox)

Comment: RegEx is way to heavy for checking a single charachter.

Answer (score 10):

try this

```
string str = "N4535";
bool isLetter = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && Char.IsLetter(str[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string input = "N4534 ";

    Regex reg = new Regex("^[a-zA-z].*$"); 

    // Match the input and write results
    Match match = reg.Match(input);

    return match.Success;
```

Answer (score 0):

1> Create a behaviour as shown [here](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html)

2> Subscribe to TextChanged event.

3> Apply RegEx  (E.g. "^[a-zA-z].*$")

4> clear text if RegEx return false.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ...}" >
  <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <b:AlphaTextBehavior/>
 </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>

public class DragBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
      // AssociatedObject.TextChanged += 
    }
}
```